# How to apply CSS(specially padding/margin ) to options or optgroup of select drop down?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Padding or margin CSS only applies to the options in FF browser. I have tried same thing in IE chrome but does not work. Can someone let me know how we can style(padding/margin) option in select menu.

Comment: Most browsers don't support this feature because it alters the experience for the user. They generally want the user to see the native OS form controls. If styling elements is critical, use a library that replaces the form controls with custom HTML that can be styled with CSS.

Comment: Why don't you show what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [DropKick JQuery library](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/) , where you can customize your dropdown (it's automatically replacing the native dropdowns with this element, so you don't need to replace your `<select>` elements in html code.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
<optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="German Cars">
<option value="vw">VW</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

</body>
</html>

Comment: All options and optgroup needs to be shown in the same vertical line. where as right now it is showing optgroup in one line & adding some padding or margin for options.

Answer (score -2):

You won't see an option for padding or margin. That's because it isn't needed. What I typically do is I wrap the select dropdown in a div and style it like so.

.myDropdown select{
    border: solid 1px red; font-weight: normal;width:300px;height:40px;font-size:12px;background:#FFC;
}

The reason padding is not available is because it really isn't needed. You can adjust the height or width of your box and the font size. Adjusting the height and width essentially adds more space around your text within the select. Anything more than adjusting these settings is just overkill. If you're really wanting that much control over styling then use something like jQuery UI or bootstrap.

Comment: Being opinionated about the use case doesn't make a good reply.

Comment: _"isn't needed"_ ? Thats not a good answer at all. That's a decision made by the designer.